# Как переписать функцию, что бы можно было копировать изображения по ссылке?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция, при её вызове копируется изображение, если задать обычный путь из локальной папки, всё работает, а если передать изображение ссылкой, нет. (изображения на сайт приходят ссылкой из базы...)

```
const copy = async () => {
const image = await fetch(
    'https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/stock-photo-159533631-1500x1000.jpg'
  ),
  blob = await image.blob();

await navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob })]);
};
copy();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить, делаю возможность копировать текст и изображения, с текстом было намного проще)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибки не пробовали отлавливать?

```js
const copy = () => fetch('https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/stock-photo-159533631-1500x1000.jpg')
                        .then((res) => res.blob())
                        .then((blob) => {
                          return navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob })]);
                        });

copy().catch(console.error); // Type image/jpeg not supported on write.
```

`ClipboardItem` не поддерживает MIME `image/jpeg`.

Чтобы этой ошибки не возникало, можно конвертить `image/jpeg` в `image/png`:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

const copy = () => fetch('https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/stock-photo-159533631-1500x1000.jpg')
                        .then((res) => res.blob())
                        .then(convertJPEGtoPNG)
                        .then((blob) => {
                          console.log('Изображение скопировано');
                          return navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob })]);
                        });

function convertJPEGtoPNG(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (blob.type !== 'image/jpeg') resolve(blob);
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const img = new Image();
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          img.onload = function() {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            canvas.toBlob((blob) => { resolve(blob) }, 'image/png');
          };
  });
}

// Важно, чтобы Document был в фокусе, иначе получите 'DOMException'
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  copy().catch(console.error); // Теперь ошибки нет
});
```

```html
<button>Copy</button>
```

В сниппете доступ к клипборду блочится, в нем он по дефолту работать не будет(надо наверное доступ запрашивать через `navigator.clipboard.permissions.query()`, проверять не стал). На [CodePen](https://codepen.io/neverm1ndo/pen/rNvNdbx?editors=0011) точно работает, можно потыкать.